# How to make spring @Value attribute session scoped

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an application.properties file with the following:

```
retry.count = 3
```

Which is injected into a Spring MVC controller

```
@Value("${retry.count}")
private int retryCount;

try{
  invokeRestCall()
}
catch(TimeOutException ex){
  if(retryCount > 0) {
  retryCount--;
  //Retry call with recursion
  }
}
```

As retryCount is injected when application loads, and not session scoped, retryCount is shared across sessions and counter wouldn't work

Scope for beans can be defined by `@Scope(value="session")`, but this is not working with `@Value` attribute and shows an error "Scope cannot be defined for fields"

Is there any other way to make fields session scoped?

Comment: wouldn't the field become session scoped when you put @Scope(value="session") at the class level?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Spring-retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Using it you can avoid managing that state and make your component stateless and as a result, make it `Singleton` instead of `Session-scoped`

Answer (score 0):

`Two parallel HTTP sessions do not share the changes done in session scoped bean instances.`([source](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-scope-example-using-scope-annotation-and-xml-for-singleton-prototype-request-session-global-session-and-application-scope-with-scoped-proxy#session)). You should add @Scope session at above the class where you have this field. Then every new http session will get its own instance of the class and thus its own version of retryCount